# Is it possible to train a binary classification neural network by only feeding it with input from only one class?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm basically trying to create a neural network that should tell me whether an input I'm giving it is valid or not. The problem is that I only have valid input with which I can train it.

Right now I am trying to come up with a working dense model that validates only mnist digits between 0 and 4. All other digits should be seen as invalid. First attempt was to train it with digits between 0 and 4 as valid and images with random pixels as invalid (with the same percent of black pixels as a normal image) but unfortunately it doesn't work. When I test it with digits between 5 and 9, they are seen as valid.

So I'm starting to think if it's even possible to train a neural network this way.

Also I realize there might be better ways to do this, maybe with an autoencoder or a different kind of network but right now I want to try this with only dense layers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is  [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification), also known as unary classification or class-modelling.

[Quick google search](https://www.quora.com/Do-you-have-any-implementation-of-one-class-classification-using-neural-network) suggests to train an [autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) and define an object as in your class if the reconstruction error is below a specific threshold.

But if you start building up something like that i would suggest you to use something like One-Class K-Nearest Neighbor or One-Class SVM first to see if you get acceptable results. If so you can improve your results with the "extremly more complicated to develop"- solution using autoencoders